# how to write java method(if String x = to String y return String z)

Tags: java, encryption, methods, caesar-cipher

Hello I want to create a table that says if `x=y`, return z. I know that my current method of doing this is probably very inefficient but this is the best I could come up with as I am a beginner. The program is a simple cipher program to change the alphabet (ie.`'a'='g'`, `'b'='h'`). I want to be able to control what values are equal to what rather than doing something like a shift/caesar cipher. 
Thank you

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {
   public static String k;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TBL1 gg=new TBL1();
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a Character");
      String chr=sc.nextLine();
      sc.close();

      for(int i=1;i<=chr.length();i++){
          k=TBL1.set2(Character.toString(chr.charAt(i-1)));
          System.out.print(k);
      }
  }
}
```

```
public class TBL1 {
    public static String chr;
    public static String set2(String character){
        if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
            chr="b";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("b")){
            chr="c";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
            chr="d";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
            chr="e";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
            chr="f";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("f")){
            chr="g";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("g")){
            chr="h";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("h")){
            chr="i";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("i")){
            chr="j";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("j")){
            chr="k";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("k")){
            chr="l";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("l")){
            chr="m";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("m")){
            chr="n";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
            chr="o";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("o")){
            chr="p";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("p")){
            chr="q";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
            chr="r";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("r")){
            chr="s";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
            chr="t";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("t")){
            chr="u";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("u")){
            chr="v";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("v")){
            chr="w";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("w")){
            chr="x";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("x")){
            chr="y";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
            chr="z";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase("z")){
            chr="a";
        }else if(character.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")){
            chr=" ";
        }

        return chr;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, can you clarify?

Comment: Please, for your sake and the readers', don't name your `String` variable `character`... at least call it `charString`!

Comment: @sleepToken my bad in the future I will be sure to not do that.

Comment: Hint 'a' + 1 == 'b'

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an approach like that. In the future, you may want to use a scrambled version.

So, let's say you work with your baseString:

```
String original = "abcdefghijk"
```

Create a second String: `String coded = "bcdefhijka";` although in your case the locations will be different.

that way, you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String original = "abcdefghijk";
    String coded = "bcdefghijka";

    char c = coded.charAt(original.indexOf('c'));
    System.out.println("c coded = " + c);
}
```

Of course, you can go further, and add an 'if indexOf(char) == -1 return char' rule

Comment: Generally there is no need to write out the ABC, even for a reordered alphabet: just *calculate* the index.

Comment: What I mean is that the `original` string isn't required; the alphabet is already present in the way characters are encoded.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes sure, but are you going to calculate that each time you want to get a char?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are creating a Caesar cipher with a shift (key) of 1. You can do this in 5 steps:

1. Go (iterate) over all characters in the string;
2. Convert each character into an index in the alphabet (ABC) for your cipher;
3. Perform a shift by adding `k` (e.g. 1 in your case), and then take the modulus using the size of the alphabet (26 for the English ABC);
4. Convert back to the (ciphertext) character from the index;
5. Append the character to a ciphertext string (using `StringBuilder`).

For a *reordered* alphabet you can replace steps 3 and 4 by using the index in a different alphabet, simply get a character at the index of your reordered alphabet string:

```
"reordered ABC".charAt(index);
```

---

Now a few things:

- conversion from character to index can be performed by simply subtracting the character value of `'A'` (`char` is a numeric value in Java);
- for decryption, note that Java's `%` operator is **not** a modulus operator, it is the **rest** operator. Create a `mod` method that does: `mod(int i, int n) = ((i % n) + n) % n` so that you handle negative values correctly;
- to handle spaces, simply test for the space and directly append it to the `StringBuilder` instance without encryption / decryption (special cases need special code).

Answer (score 0):

for each lower case character get the next character value and append that into string buffer.

```
private static char getNextChar(char value) {
    char a = 'a', z = 'z';
    int shiftKey = 1;
    if (Character.isLowerCase(value)){
        int nextValue = value + shiftKey;
        if (nextValue > z)
            nextValue = a + nextValue % z;
        return (char)nextValue;
    }
    return value;
}
```